# For developing an IntelliJ Plugin, use JavaFX to build a dialog window without needing to start an application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, intellij-plugin

I am writing an Intellij Plugin and need to build a rather complex dialog in it. A dialog that would be really tiring to do in swing. So i want to know if i can shortcut it and use JavaFx to design and programm said dialog.
AFAIK you need JavaFX to be started from a class extending "Application" which in turn needs to be started as seperate process.
Is there a way to just build a dialog in fx and call it from another class without the need of a separate proccess?

Comment: Just [start up the JavaFX runtime](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup(java.lang.Runnable)) when you start the plugin. Then you can create and show your dialog on the JavaFX Application Thread (via `Platform.runLater()`) any time you need. You should also call `Platform.exit()` when the plugin terminates, if at all possible.

Comment: Does this help? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14250-javafx-runtime-for-plugins

Comment: Do you happen to know how i can import this plugin to my plugin. The plugins homepage states that     <depends>com.intellij.javafx</depends> needs to be added to the plugin.xml but gradle refuses to load it "cannot resolve plugin". 
do i also need to add something in the build.gradle if yes what exactly

Comment: That "IntelliJ Plugin" is an important part of your Question. I edited your title and tags appropriately.

Comment: Please see https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-dependencies.html . If the problem remains I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.